InvalidExchange error in Brightway 2.5 during writing to database
As I was importing a file from the function
`dict_activities=create_target_databases(r"Artikel2/02_BW_datasets/DB_Energy.xlsx", 'Energy'),
# Step 3: Import data from the specified Excel file
    imp = bio.ExcelImporter(filepath)
    imp.apply_strategies()
    imp.match_database(database, fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
    imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
    imp.match_database('biosphere3', fields=('name', 'unit', 'categories'))
    imp.write_database()

which has the above lines of code in it, I got an InvalidExchange error.Excel File for DB_Energy. this error occured when I migrated from BW2 to BW2.5.
I tried checking missing fields, as suggested by Chris Mutel in other posts which gave the output message:Applied 16 strategies in 5.70 seconds
7 datasets
    7 exchanges
    7 unlinked exchanges
    Type technosphere: 7 unique unlinked exchanges.

I also tried adding column name "reference product" and removing "unit" from the excel file, also added them here in the code below and re ran the code, issue still persisted.
Step 3: Import data from the specified Excel file
    imp = bio.ExcelImporter(filepath)
    imp.apply_strategies()
    imp.match_database(database, fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
    imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
    imp.match_database('biosphere3', fields=('name', 'unit', 'categories'))
    imp.write_database().


Please guide what changes I can make and do not hesitate to ask for any other code snippets required if so.

It's very hard to know what went wrong without access to the data you are trying to import. There is no general fix here - it really depends on your data, and the databases you are trying to link it to.
